# Is a key/value datastore like Redis appropriate for authorization data?

Tags: security, redis, authorization, nosql

I have my authentication elsewhere.  This is only for authorization.

But for authorization, I need to store the information mapping somewhere, so that user X is authorized to see page a and resource b on that page.

Is this something Redis is usable for?  Is there an advantage over a RDBMS?  The information doesn't change much.

Answer (score 1):

Redis can be used for that if you make sure that it is not accessible by untrusted code or users. Anyone who has access to the Redis instance can read and change its contents. In contrast, most RDBMSs provide very fine-grained access control, so you can make the authorization tables read-only to the web application server, while the administrator can change them.